# Programmatically update Drupal CCK field

Tags: drupal, location, cck

How can I update a cck field programmatically?

I am trying the following code, without any success:

```
$node->location[field_location][0][city]    =   'tracker city';
    $node->location[field_location][0][latitude]    =   8.888888;
    $node->location[field_location][0][longitude]   =   9.999999;
```

I am aware I could directly interact with the database but I am looking for a different solution.

Comment: Where are you putting that code? That will update the value of the field in the node object, but you will still need to save the node after the change.

Comment: The code is in a custom module in hook_nodeapi. I am checking for presave and then executing the code. I also tried calling node_save after my code but the just breaks the site and results in a white screen with the message "Connection terminated unexpectedly"

Comment: It is possible that your module's weight in the 'system' table is less than the weight of the 'location' module. This would cause your module's 'presave' to be overwritten by the location module. I am guessing both your module and the weight of the 'location' module are set to 0 in the 'system' table. Try changing your module's weight to 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to put this in your presave, and have it save properly. I'm not 100% sure that city, latitude, and longitude are the correct keys, but I'm leaving them since you had them.

```
$node->field_location[0][city]      = 'tracker city';
$node->field_location[0][latitude]  = 8.888888;
$node->field_location[0][longitude] = 8.999999;
```

If that does not work, you should install the Devel module and use the Node 'Devel' tab to view the node object and see exactly what the proper format is.

Comment: Regarding the array keys, I inspected the Devel output and used the listed array data. It all seems correct but the damn thing just wont co-operate.

Comment: After much thought, I came to the conclusion that the reason my cck updates are not working ( especially for inserting new cck fields ) is because the cck array index does not exist if I try and do something like <b>$node->field_location[1][city]</b>. So, I would need a more robust programmed solution to handle this issue. When I find the working solution, I will be sure to post it here

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$node->language = LANGUAGE_NONE;
$node->field_custom_name[$node->language][0]['value'] = 'This is a custom field value';
?>
```

See [here](http://lyphuong.drupalgardens.com/content/how-programmatically-create-nodes-comments-and-taxonomies-drupal-7?page=3) for more info.